# How can I cange settings for https://cla.opensource.microsoft.com

Tags: github, open-source

Is there a way to change the CLA settings I've picked in the past for https://cla.opensource.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 0):

Currently changing settings is not implemented. See this feature request for more information: https://github.com/cla-assistant/cla-assistant/issues/380